# ScriptBundle adding both full and minified file in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have the following ScriptBundle defined in BundleConfig.cs-

```
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
          bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/yepnope").Include(
                "~/Scripts/yepnope.{version}.js"));
       }
    }
```

It isn't in fact the only bundle, but that is all in there that is pertinent to the question - the rest is just other bundle definitions.

When in "debug" mode as set in the web.config-

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Both the full and minified versions of the script are sent to the browser-

```
<script src="/Scripts/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/yepnope.1.5.4.js"></script>
```

The script is added using the HTML helper like so-

```
@section HeadScripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/yepnope")
}
```

This is an MVC4 project running in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Whatever I do I cannot get the {version} wildcard to behave as described in the [Microsoft documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)-

> Note: Unless EnableOptimizations is true or the debug attribute in the
>   compilation Element  in the Web.config file is set to false, files
>   will not be bundled or minified. Additionally, the .min version of
>   files will not be used,  **the full debug versions will be selected**.
>
> For ASP.NET MVC 4, this means with a  debug configuration, the file
>   jquery-1.7.1.js will be added to the bundle. In a release
>   configuration,  jquery-1.7.1.min.js will be added. The bundling
>   framework follows several common conventions such as:
>
> - **Selecting “.min” file for release when “FileX.min.js” and “FileX.js”
>     exist**.
> - **Selecting the non “.min” version for debug**.
> - Ignoring “-vsdoc”
>     files (such as jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js), which are used only by
>     IntelliSense.
>
> The {version} wild card matching shown above is used to
>   automatically create a jQuery bundle with the appropriate  version of
>   jQuery in your Scripts folder.  In this example, using a wild card
>   provides the following benefits:
>
> - Allows you to use NuGet to update to a newer jQuery version without
>     changing the preceding bundling code or jQuery references in your view
>     pages.
> - **Automatically selects the full version for debug configurations
>     and the ".min" version for release builds.**

If I add "EnableOptimizations" it seems to behave as expected.

Has anyone else noticed this or found a solution?

Comment: Publishing without the debug attribute also appears to cause it to generate a single minified version of the file from the full .js file - the minified variable names are different to those in the provided minified version.

Comment: You probably mean for that file to be named `.min.js` and not `-min.js`.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev It probably came as `-min.js`. It's a common problem using NuGet package with MVC4: you grab a package and it comes with a `.js` and either a `-min.js` or `.min.js`. If you get a `.min.js` file, everything *should* work. But if you get a `-min.js` file it just causes problems. Better to get rid of it entirely, as in my answer.

Comment: @TimothyShields removing it works, but following the docs and having a '.min.js' file works too, and in a quick test, the optimized file was smaller using the .min than when it wasn't there, so I will advocate renaming the file and using optimization as designed.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev If the default minifier is less efficient than some other one that was used to create the packaged `min.js`, you can switch the minifier to be that instead...

Comment: As @TimothyShields correctly suggested this package came via NuGet and thus I didn't choose the name. I'm ashamed to say it honestly didn't occur to me that there wouldn't be a (trivial) regex alternation between a period and hyphen - the latter is also a fairly popular pattern amongst NuGet packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC4 only knows how to handle a `.min.js` file. It doesn't recognize `-min.js` (with a dash).

The way I typically do this, with easy success, is to get rid of any `.min.js` or `-min.js` files provided by libraries that provide both a `.js` and either a `.min.js` or `-min.js`. By default, MVC will automatically minify  any bundled `.js` files when you deploy your website, so there's no need to use the provided `.min.js` or `-min.js` files.

This isn't necessarily a direct answer to your particular question - it's a way to circumvent the problem entirely.